# File cannot be download in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am having problem when trying to make a page that can download files from folder. In the page, I can display the list of the files in the list but when I click the download link, nothing happen and I cannot download the files. Below is my coding:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGrid();
        }
    }

    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/download"));
            List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
            }
            GridView1.DataSource = files;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }


    protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
        Response.ContentType = ContentType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
        Response.WriteFile(filePath);
        Response.End();
    }

 }
```

Here is my HTML markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText = "No files uploaded">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="File Name" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text = "Download" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Value") %>' runat="server" OnClick = "DownloadFile"></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Is there anything that I overlooked or is there anything missing that made my page cannot download the files. Thanks.

Comment: Are there any server errors? Is filePath the value you expected?

Comment: there is no server error. I can already display the page and the file list, but when I click the link, the browser did not download the file. yes, the filepath is already correct.

Comment: Try to Remove  if (!IsPostBack) from BindGrid You Already Call it From Page_Load

Comment: Just for kicks, read the file into a byte array and then do response.BinaryWrite. I wonder if there are some permission issues with WriteFile reading from your downloads folder.

Comment: Tried remove the (!isPostBack) but I still cannot download the files. I have put word document, txt and also pdf files just to try to test the coding.

Comment: Already turned into byte array using response.BinaryWrite but the files still cannot be download.

Comment: @namasayadin this code working fine i tried it on my machine, try to run with any other browser.

Comment: @Irfan Will do sir. Maybe its my browser that cannot download the file.

Comment: @Irfan Already tried another browser but still cannot download the files. Do you copy my whole coding and did not modified it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't wire up an onclick event and have it work with command arguments. You need to use the Command event instead. Give it a CommandName, like "DownLoadFile". Because this is in a grid, the grid will most likely intercept the command. You'll want to over-ride the grids RowCommand event and trap the commandname to determine if it's your linkbutton that just fired. If so, you should be able to access the CommandArgument directly from the RowCommand event arguments.

Comment: Can you show me of some examples. I am new to c# and I am afraid I does not fully clear about your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your Asp code is same and try to use this C# code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGrid();
        }
    }

    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
    }
    private void BindGrid()
    {
     string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/download"));
     List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
     foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
     {
        files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
     }
       GridView1.DataSource = files;
       GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
        Response.ContentType = ContentType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
        Response.WriteFile(filePath);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: I have upvote. Dont know who downvote. I have try to copy and use your coding but still cannot download. I have a web config page so maybe the problem occur because of that?

Comment: I have tried using other laptops but still the files cannot be download. Do you have tested download some files using my code?

Comment: @namasayadin what is your reason for upvote? The post has no explanation and did not work for you...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Because he is trying to help me because this code works for him but not for me. Does the file web.config also can be a factor that make me cannot download the files even the list of files has been displayed?

Comment: @namasayadin that is a strange reason for upvote - there is no indication why that code should work at all... (but obviously you free to use your votes whatever way you want).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am new to stack overflow and maybe i have the wrong impression but anyway thanks for the advice.